# What is Lenin saying about "republican slogans" in 'The Socialist Revolution and the Right of Nations to Self-Determination'

Tags: marxism, peace-studies

> The fact that the struggle for national liberation against one
> imperialist power may, under certain circumstances, be utilized by
> another “Great” Power in its equally imperialist interests should have
> no more weight in inducing Social Democracy to renounce its
> recognition of the right of nations to self-determination than the
> numerous case of the bourgeoisie utilizing republican slogans for the
> purpose of political deception and financial robbery, for example, in
> the Latin countries, have had in inducing them to renounce
> republicanism

https://www.marxists.org/archive/lenin/works/1916/jan/x01.htm#fwV22P151F01

I am trying to work out whether, supposing a war is fought against an oppressor nation and this war is in the interest of a "great" imperialist power - specifically its economic interests - then Lenin thinks it is not a "revolutionary war".

Is Lenin comparing the utilisation - economically or militarily - of anti colonial struggle by other great powers to a reactionary republicanism he would *not* support? Or is he merely pointing to how the bourgeoisie can *appear* to co-opt republicanism and anti-colonial struggle?

I would have thought perhaps, but I'm unsure if he would think that freedom for Ireland in the 19th century - which he unequivocally supports - would necessarily involve economic success for some "great" imperialist power. Aftfer-all, the saturation of world markets was something Rosa Luxemburg argued for, and I think she was opposed to all wars of national independence, against Lenin.

Comment: The statement is quite convoluted, but it seems to mean that, according to Lenin, there is no "absolute" right to self-determination.

Comment: ok. i doubt i will get any better comments or answers here. dunno why i bothered really. good to feel someone understood what i was asking, at least @MauroALLEGRANZA